# How to scale svg size to exactly wrap its content?

Tags: css, svg

I have a very simple svg with a circle inside:

```
<div>
  <svg className="main-svg">
    <circle pathLength="25" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Then if I style it:

```
svg {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

The svg will take up 250px width and height, but the circle inside it will be much smaller, so there's unwanted white space around the circle. Is it possible to make the svg wrap the circle without adding space, so that defining the width of height of the svg will result in setting the width and height of the circle inside it?

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fwmjzn?file=style.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set radius attribute value to `50%`

```css
svg {border: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
            <circle pathLength="25" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" />
        </svg>
```